# select random but ordered sequence of data in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to select a sample of data in R where the first observation is random, but the following observations are ordered by the original data-set. For example, say I have the following data:

```
x <- c(2, 3, 4, 8, 4, 6, 5, 4, 4)
```

And I want to randomly select a sequence of `n = 3` observations. If the first observation randomly selected was for the third integer, `4`, then my sample would be `4, 8, 4` and would retain this order.

I've tried to use `seq` and `sample` as so:

```
x.sample <- sample(x, seq(x), size = 3, replace = F)
x.sample <- seq(from = sample(x, size = 1), length.out = 3)
```

but the data is not in index order. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: What happens when I do the second one is it randomly selects a value from my sample and then starts the sequence from here, increasing by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
x[(s <- sample(length(x)-2, 1)):(s+2)]
```

Sample a random starting point, then extract from the sequence.

Comment: Thanks! That's awesome